# .NET: puzzling cryptographic exception in RsaCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I get a cryptographic exception in the following code, and the exception states: invalid flags specified

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int)strength);
rsa.Encrypt(new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 }, false); // forcing the key to generate
```

I have tried to set cspParameters but there is no difference.
I think it only happens when I set a large bitsize. (strength value)

Comment: Please post it as answer and accept it or delete your question

Comment: Never mind, the source of the problem was that I set it to a value larger than 16384. (which is the max bitsize for RSA in dot net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, the source of the problem was that I set it to a value larger than 16384. (which is the max bitsize for RSA in dot net).